# If Applet are going to be obsolete, how to execute java code in the client Virtual Machine?

Tags: java, web-applications, applet, javabeans

I am wondering how to make the client execute java code since Applets are going to become obsolete.

Suppose that a web-application is required to make computationally intensive calculations: how could the server, in response to the client request, distribute to the client the needed java code and let the client Virtual Machine make the calculation?

I am new with Web-Applications, I do not master the technical language and, perhaps, I need a reference to a good book to read.

Comment: Does it have to be in Java? These days, web applications tend to target the Javascript or WASM virtual machines that are natively supported by browsers (no need for a plugin).

Comment: Yes, I should use Java. The main goal of the application should be calling computationally intensive methods of a java library, resident in the server, from an html page without installing anything. If Applets were allowed, I could distribute to the client an applet in correspondence of each method call.

Comment: "Without installing anything"  means Java is not an option. If these things are pure computations, you should be able to express them in Javascript or WASM (you can compile C or Rust to that). If these things are not pure computations (but need to do a lot of other things or have context), it may not be very easy to ship them to client machines (which don't have access to resources on your server or even, as they will be sandboxed, on the client either).

Comment: Let's say: "anything else than Java". To give a concrete example: some method should elaborate a file resident in the client filesystem but the computation is highly intensive so that the server cannot do it. How could I realize such an application? Translating the Java Library into a JS Library is not an option.

Comment: A Java applet won't have access to files residing in the client file system either. There are severe restrictions in place for code that is allowed to be downloaded and automatically executed. Are you sure you cannot have your clients download and install an application (which can then be written in Java and have auto-update capabilities)? There used to be Java WebStart for that, but that's just as dead as applets now.

Comment: @Thilo Accessing a java application through a browser, without installing anything else than java, would have been the most attractive feature of my project. However, if well understand, there is no way to do it. Nevertheless, I suppose you have well understood my intentions so, perhaps, you can suggest me something to read before I design my application.